# Any way (even if roundabout) of having access to other countries' Apple Books catalog?

Tags: ios-appstore, books

My App Store account is Brazilian, and I find the Apple Books catalog to be very lacking, especially in native language editions.

As an example, the single book by Kurt Vonnegut that's available in native English is Slaughterhouse Five — books such as Cat's Cradle and Sirens of Titan are available only in Portuguese, and others such as Breakfast of Champions are unavailable even in translated versions.

I believe the selection is far better in the US version, so I'd love to know if there's any way (even if hacky or roundabout) of getting access to it without messing with my App Store, Apple News, and other services that are tied to my nationality.

What can I do to gain access to other countries' Apple Books content to buy/download?

Comment: The best thing is to just use another store, like amazon, and read with the kindle app.

Comment: A decent VPN that lets you select servers from a variety of different countries should work. When I select Toronto as my server, I get news an Amazon from Canada. Picking Chicago as your server might get you into American App store. Buying there might still be troublesome, depending on how picky Apple's store software is.

Comment: This seems like an entirely different problem than News. In fact, I do have access to Apple News on all my devices, because they have their countries set as United States. But this doesn't influence anything on Apple Books, because it follows the App Store country rather than the device country.